# array.Add() in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there something like the .Add() function in MATLAB?
I have void (at first step) array, and I would like to put filtered experimental data in it (I don't know how much data I will find during experiment) in C# syntax is quite simple:

```
 List<T> filteredData = new List<T>(); // declare and initialize 'array' of unknown length(right now it 0) typeof T
 .
 .
 //do something and find proper result - "value" variable   
 //save it to filtered array
 filteredData.Add(value); // now length of filteredData == 1
```

And here goes MATLAB:

```
filteredArray = [];
%...
for n =2 : count -1
 foundedValue = experimentData[n];
 % how to do
 %filteredArray.ADD(foundedValue) ?? 
end
```

Comment: You might want to use "found" instead of "founded". Found is the past participle of find and founded is the past of other verbs with different meanings (build, establish, melt)

Comment: @VladimirFrolov: `append` is for mupad objects, not for "normal" matlab arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filteredArray(end+1)=foundedValue
```

Comment: Does matlab really freezes, or is it only very slow? If it is very slow, you should consider preallocating `filteredArray`.

Comment: really freez( perhaps this is because of filteredArray = []; initialization?

Comment: oh, it works/ filteredArray(1,end+1) done the trick) I am still c# thinking person) Thank you Daniel!

Comment: You definitely ran into a bug of Matlab if it freezes in this case. Both should work, maybe restarting Matlab fixes it.